# Meteor.call returning undefined from server to client

Tags: javascript, callback, meteor

I am trying to make a HTTP call to a remote server in my app

i have a package with a function which handles the actual call and then converts the xml to json

```
myPackage = {
baseUrl: "http://12.34.56.78:8080/api",

getBatchList: function() {
    var url = this.baseUrl + "/batchList.xml";

    HTTP.get(url, {auth: "user:pass"}, function(err, res) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(res);
            xml2js.parseStringSync(res.content, function(error, result){
                if (!error) {
                    console.log(result); //the result is displayed
                    return result;
                };
            });
        };
    });
}
}
```

i then have a Meteor.method declared on the server so I can invoke the function from the client since myPackage is only available on the server (which it must be, since its making http calls to outside the domain which i cant do from the client).

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
Meteor.methods({
    getBatchList: function() {
        myPackage.getBatchList(function(error, result) {
            if (!error && result) {
                console.log(result); //nothing is logged to the console
                return result;
            };
        });
    }
})
}
```

however it seems that results are not being passed into the `getBatchList` method for some reason, which i suspect is that the i have something wrong with the way the callback is being structured (i have no clue);

and lastly on the client is calling the method

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
Template.hello.events({
    'click input' : function () {

        Meteor.call("getBatchList", function(error, result) {
            if (result && !error) {
                console.log(result);
            } else {
                console.log("nothing returned!!!");
            };
        });
    }
});
}
```

which would also not get any results from the server no error or result.

any help would be appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: I don't see in your code logging errors to the console. Try that to see if you are getting an error returned from the get rather than a result

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that the code running on the server was asynchronous including the HTTP request and the functions themselves. i changed the code as follows

mainly the instead of returning the result of the HTTP call we are now returning the call itself.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        getList: function() {
            var req = myPackage.getList();
            return req;
        }
    })
};
```

and the myPackage getList function to

```
myPackage = {
    baseUrl: "http://12.34.56.78:8080/",

    getList: function() {
        var url = this.baseUrl + "/getList.xml";

        var req = HTTP.get(url, {auth: "user:pass"});
        if (req.statusCode === 200) {
            xml2js.parseStringSync(req.content, function(error, result){
                if (!error) {
                    req = result;
                };
            });

        };
        return req;
    }
}
```